# Angular form.$dirty and error only on dirty fields

Tags: forms, validation, angularjs

I have several form error messages inside a container, and I want to ng-show the outer container only if there are specific errors ng-shown inside.

My goal is that if one field (say, email) gets dirty+invalid, we see the error box. Then the user fixes the email. Now all the other stuff is pristine, and the dirty email is valid. I want to hide the errorbox now.

The error box looks like this (Jade template, but you can see the HTML in it):

```
    div.errorbox(ng-show="register.$dirty && register.$error")
        h3 Warning
        p(ng-show="register.email.$dirty && register.email.$error") The email address you entered is not valid!
        p(ng-show="register.password.$dirty && register.password.$error.required") Please enter a password.
        p(ng-show="register.password.$dirty && register.password.$error.minlength") Password is too short.
        p(ng-show="register.confirmpassword.$dirty && register.confirmpassword.$error.required") Please confirm your password.
        p(ng-show="form.confirmpassword.$dirty && reg.match") Passwords do not match
```

Basically if there are any errors, I want to show both the surrounding box and container. If there arent specific messages, I want to hide the container.

The only thing I can do now is list all the inner conditions twice, on the outer container. But that seems dumb.

Is there an angular way to do this?

Is there a recommended way to do this?

What is the easy way to do this?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Your `.errorbox` container is already set up to show only when form is dirty and has errors. Why would you need to _"... list all the inner conditions twice, on the outer container"_?

Comment: Well, let's say my email is dirty and invalid. Then the form shows stuff. Then the user fixes email. I want the errorbox to disapear, as the other stuff hasn't yet triggered. Edit: added a sentence explaining that. Thanks for a very useful comment.

Comment: Hmm, when you fix the email, the `register.$error` will equal to `false`, thus hiding the `.errorbox`. The HTML in your example should be working exactly how you're describing your goals. Does it not? Also, the _"if one field gets invalid, we see the form"_ part is a bit unclear. Isn't the form supposed to be visible all the time? Care to provide a plunker?

Comment: No, no, I meant container. And the form is not valid. When I fix the email, register.$error is still true - because password is failing minlength. The password length error itself is hidden, as it is still pristine, but the form is dirty and has errors.